# Django UserCreationForm add request.user.pk ?

Tags: python, django, createuser

Hi i need add request user pk to UserCreationForm. I try many times, but with out results. In my dashboard i have user owner and i have user seller.
One model for all 3 types user. So Owner can create another user with role=seller, but for this i need add parent field with param=request.user.pk  to seller

Custom UserModel

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


USER = 0
OWNER = 1
SELLER = 2
user_type_choice = (
    (USER, 'User'),
    (OWNER, 'Owner'),
    (SELLER, 'Seller'),
)


class User(AbstractUser):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=user_type_choice, default=USER)
    idn = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, default=None, null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, default=None, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    tariff = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
```

forms.py

```
class SellerRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2') """try add and remove 'parent' here in felds """

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(SellerRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.role = ROLE_SELLER
    # try add user.parent = self.request.user.pk 
    # but it does not work

    if commit:
        user.save()

    return user
```

## views.py

```
def register_seller(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SellerRegisterForm(request.POST)     # create form object
    if form.is_valid():
        #try add new_form = form.save(commit=False)
        # new_form.parent = request.user.pk
        # new_form.save() but it not working

        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login')

else:
    form = SellerRegisterForm()
return render(request, 'register_owner.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: what does "it does not work" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: in user with role sellere creates, but without parent = request.user.pk

Comment: Try `user.parent = self.request.user`

Comment: dosent work. i write coment i my forms.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the user object through the form's `__init__` method.

```
class SellerRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(SellerRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and in your view:

```
form = SellerRegisterForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
```

Then simply use `self.user` anywhere in your form class.

Comment: thx. i try some think like this but with instance and initial. thank you wery much